# Regular expression: use any chars as delimiter except a-zA-z and "."

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

`in.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");`

this expression can use any non-letter `char` as `delimiter` `(eg, input abc@, abc will be stored; input`abc.`, abc will be store)`.
However, I don't want to ignore `"."` because I want to use it to end the input.
How can I modify the `regular expression` above?.

Comment: Can you just include `.` in the negative character set?

Comment: What about [A-Za-z.]

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a wildcard in regex's syntax meaning "any character". If you want to use it as a "real" character, you need to escape it with a `\`:

```
in.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z\.]+");
// Escapting here -------^
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need to escape the `.` in that context (a character class).  The only characters that do / might need to be escaped in a character class are `^`, `[`, `]`, `&` and `-`.